# Send Java values to a web page

Tags: java, string, variables, int

I have 2 variables in my Java code.
My code looks like this:

```
String user = "Example";
int score = "100"
```

Now what I want, is to send these to a web page.
Looking something like this:

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <td>user</td>
      <td>score</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

How would I go on about this?

Excuse my weak English, it would be great if you can help.

Answer (score 4):

inside your Servlet class:

```
public class TestServlet extends HttpServlet {
  protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
      doPost(request, response);
  }

  protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
      String user = "Example";
      int score = 100;

      //Set your attribute in your request scope
      request.setAttribute("user", user);
      request.setAttribute("score", score);

      //Set your attribute in your Session scope
      //request.getSession().setAttribute("user", user);
      //request.getSession().setAttribute("score", score);



    //Other Stuffs
  }

}
```

inside your jsp page you can fetch your value in two ways : 1-Scriplet 2-JSTL

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>user</td>
        <td>score</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td><%=request.getAttribute("user")%></td>
        <td><%=request.getAttribute("score")%></td>
    </tr>

    <!-- IF YOU HAVE JSTL NAMESPACE ENABLED YOU CAN FETCH IT LIKE THIS -->
    <%--  
    <tr>
        <td>${user}</td>
        <td>${score}</td>
    </tr>
    --%>
</table>
```

to enable JSTL inside your JSP you should have add JSTL Library to your project first and then add this namespace at the top of your JSP page :

> < %@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>

Good Luck !

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are using servlets,you can use `request` parameter to pass values

Send data

```
  request.setAttribute("user ","Example");
  request.setAttribute("score ", 100);
```

receive data

```
  request.getAttribute("user");
  request.getAttribute("score");
```